# Compare value in R data frame after certain index

Tags: r, dataframe, indexing, compare

I have a `data.frame` as given below. I want to get the index/row number where (b-a)>8 but I want to compare them after row 7 not from row 1. I have written the code to get me the row number where b-a>8 satisfies but it checks from row 1. How to check it from row 7?

```
a <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16)
b <- c(2,12,4,5,2,5,8,5,7,19,6,7,4,23,1,2)

df <- data.frame(a,b)

which((df$b-df$a)>8)[1]
```

**Desired output:** Row number 10 not 2.

Comment: What do you expect as your output?

Comment: @Onyambu, I have edited my question. Please have a look.

Answer (score 0):

One can start with offset as in both vectors as:

```
which((df$b[7:nrow(df)]-df$a[7:nrow(df)])>8)
#[1] 8
```

Answer (score 0):

This is just a math calculation

```
(which(with(df[-(1:7),],b-a>8))+7)[1]
[1] 10
(a<-which((df$b-df$a)>8))[a>7][1]
[1] 10
```